# error while installing extension

Tags: joomla1.5

there is a error called Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package.while installing the module in joomla1.5. there is the xml file but the version notified in the xml file is 1.6. Is it becoz of that.How can i solve the problem.the module that i downloaded is from http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/select-box-menus

Comment: There are 7 modules on this page, which one did you download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is only one 1.6 native extension on that page I will assume you are installing Simple Select Box. There are versions depending on which version of Joomla you are using. The correct download for J!1.5 is here - http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/10339/40125/mod_SSB_1.5.4.zip